# Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, google-places-api

I'm trying to extract the info from a [json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaEeX.png) array and i'm getting this error

"Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'"

here

```
     if let rev = place.details?["reviews"] as? [[String:Any]] {
   if let ver = rev["author_name"] as? String {    // <- IN THIS LINE I GET THE ERROR  

             }       
        }
```

i know that if i cast the type as `[String : Any]` instead of `[[String:Any]]` it will work, but in this case i have to cast it as an array of arrays otherwise it doesn't read the json, so how can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[[String:Any]]` is an array. It can be only subscripted by `Int` index.

You have to iterate over the array for example:

```
if let reviews = place.details?["reviews"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    for review in reviews {
        if let authorName = review["author_name"] as? String {
           // do something with authorName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you not use `forEach` loop here

Comment: @AzmalTech A `for` loop is more descriptive regarding the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access an item in an array with a `String`. You have to use `Int`

`[[String:Any]]` This is an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

`[[String:Any]]` is a two dimensional **Array**. It can be only subscripted using **Int** index.

It is better to use a `forEach` loop, e.g.

```
if let reviews = place.details?["reviews"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    reviews?.forEach { review in
        if let authorName = review["author_name"] as? String {
           // do something with authorName
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up dictionaries and arrays here.
If you want to access an element in an array, you have to use an `Int` index like this

```
let a = ["test", "some", "more"] // your array
let b = a[0] // print(b) = "test"
```

If you want to access an element in a dictionary, you can access it via its key, in your case a `String`

```
let dict: [String: Any] = ["aKey": "someValue"]
let value = dict["aKey"] // print(value) = "someValue"
```

In your case you have an array of dictionaries, each of them containing information about a review. If you want to access the author of one of your reviews, you have to first get the review dictionary out of your array like this:

```
if let reviews = place.details?["reviews"] as? [[String:Any]],
   let review = reviews[0] {
      // here you can access the author of the review then:
      if let author = review["author_name"] as? String {
          // do something
      }
}
```

Instead of accessing just the first review like in my example, you can also loop via the array to access all of the reviews one by one

Comment: True, I usually use a "safe" subscript that returns an optional instead of crashing when the index is out of bounds.